# Expecting something custom error

Tags: elm

I'm new to elm and trying to decode some Json. But I keep getting this error about an expectation that it is not getting.

Below is an example of the code. I'm not sure what is it expecting.

```
module JsonTest exposing (..)
import Json.Decode
import Json.Decode.Pipeline

--Model
type alias Model = 
    { msg : String
    , tlps : List Tlp
    }

decodeTlps : Json.Decode.Decoder Model
decodeTlps = 
    Json.Decode.Pipeline.decode Model
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.hardcoded "Got Data"
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "tlps" (Json.Decode.list decodeTlp)

type alias Tlp =
    { title : String
    , trendingTopic : Bool
    , synonym : Bool
    , summaryDate : String
    , lastFeatureAdded : String
    , modifiedDate : String
    }

decodeTlp : Json.Decode.Decoder Tlp
decodeTlp = 
    Json.Decode.Pipeline.decode Tlp
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "title" (Json.Decode.string)
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.optional "trendingTopic" (Json.Decode.bool) False
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.optional "synonym" (Json.Decode.bool) False
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.optional "summaryDate" (Json.Decode.string) "1/1/2016"
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.optional "lastFeatureAdded" (Json.Decode.string) "1/1/2016"
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.optional "modifiedDate" (Json.Decode.string) "1/1/2016"

json = 
 """
{
  "tlps": [
    {
      "title": "Topic 1",
      "trendingTopic": false,
      "synonym": false,
      "summaryDate": null,
      "lastFeatureAdded": null,
      "modifiedDate": null
    },
    {
      "title": "Topic 2",
      "trendingTopic": false,
      "synonym": false,
      "summaryDate": null,
      "lastFeatureAdded": null,
      "modifiedDate": null
    },
    {
      "title": "Topic 3",
      "trendingTopic": false,
      "synonym": false,
      "summaryDate": null,
      "lastFeatureAdded": null,
      "modifiedDate": null
    },
    {
      "title": "Topic 4",
      "trendingTopic": false,
      "synonym": false,
      "summaryDate": null,
      "lastFeatureAdded": null,
      "modifiedDate": null
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

If I run the following in the repl I get

```
> import JsonTest
> import Json.Decode
> Json.Decode.decodeString JsonTest.decodeTlps JsonTest.json
Err "Expecting something custom at _.tlps[3] but instead got: {\"title\":\"Topic 4\",\"trendingTopic\":false,\"synonym\":false,\"summaryDate\":null,\"lastFeatureAdded\":null,\"modifiedDate\":null}"
    : Result.Result String TLPDashboard.Model
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

[`elm-decode-pipeline version 2.0.0`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/2.0.0/) includes a fix for this issue, so that `null` is handled by `optional` as `Nothing`.

**Original answer for version 1.1.2**

The current version of [`elm-decode-pipeline v1.1.2`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/1.1.2/) does not handle explicit nulls as you may expect.

When using `optional`, if a field isn't in the json, the decoder succeeds, but if the value is specified as null (e.g. `"summaryDate": null`), the decoder will fail with the message you've posted.

There are a few ways around this:

1. You could wrap change the type optional fields to include `Maybe` (e.g. `summaryDate : Maybe String`, then change the decoder accordingly and in the process, remove the hardcoded dates in favor of `Nothing`:

```elm
|> Json.Decode.Pipeline.optional "summaryDate" (Json.Decode.maybe Json.Decode.string) Nothing
```

2. Alternatively, you could bypass the `Json.Decode.Pipeline` code in favor of defining decoders using native Elm functionality.

```elm
decodeTlp : Json.Decode.Decoder Tlp
decodeTlp = 
    let
      optional decoder default = Json.Decode.oneOf [decoder, Json.Decode.succeed default]
    in
      Json.Decode.object6 Tlp
        ("title" := Json.Decode.string)
        (optional ("trendingTopic" := Json.Decode.bool) False)
        (optional ("synonym" := Json.Decode.bool) False)
        (optional ("summaryDate" := Json.Decode.string) "1/1/2016")
        (optional ("lastFeatureAdded" := Json.Decode.string) "1/1/2016")
        (optional ("modifiedDate" := Json.Decode.string) "1/1/2016")
```

3. Alternatively, you could post a pull request to the maintainers of [`elm-decode-pipeline`](https://github.com/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/tree/master) to add in the expected handling of explicit nulls. **Edit**: I created [a pull request](https://github.com/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/pull/9) adding correct handling of nulls.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked great. I see you answer a lot of Elm question, thanks for helping us all out! I've only been using it for a little more than a week and I'm still getting used to the composition of the functions.